# javascript add Single Event Lister for multiple events like ajax function callbacks succss, fail etc

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-dispatching

I want to crate javascript object that accepts setting and provide multiple events with single addListener function. for example `addListener({success: callback,fail:callback})` etc. I hope my requirement is clear.

```
var myCustomObject=new MyCustomeObject({name:'anu', age:'30'});

myCustomObject.addListener({

success: function(e){ console.log(e)},
fail: function(ef){ console.log(ef)}

});
```

Comment: search the publish-subscribe design pattern or extend `EventEmitter` if on node.js

Comment: thank you Nikos for your promt response, But I need in native javascript only

Comment: what do you mean with native javascript. also what do you want listen to if you put an listener on it

Comment: And how do you expect an event 'fail'? The closest I could imagine, is to have a separate `error` event with its own lisreners...

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own EventEmitter like this:

```
const EventEmitter = function () {
    this.events = {};
};
```

Then you need to create function for subscribe:

```
EventEmitter.prototype.on = function (event, listener) {
if (typeof this.events[event] !== 'object') {
    this.events[event] = [];
}

this.events[event].push(listener);
};
```

and of course function for emit:

```
EventEmitter.prototype.emit = function (event) {
let i, listeners, length, args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

if (typeof this.events[event] === 'object') {
    listeners = this.events[event].slice();
    length = listeners.length;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        listeners[i].apply(this, args);
    }
}
};
```

Comment: That's good, but misses the main point of the question: having a success and a fail callback...

Comment: @FZs, you should define what success and fail are and how they are triggered, then you can augment the basic eventemitter presented in this answer

Comment: @NikosM. I just mentioned that it doesn't answer the question. I agree with that the question is unclear, that's why *I* didn't answer it (*if you can't answer a question, then don't answer it*). IMO, the question should also be closed until it gets clarified.

Comment: @FZs, oops I thought you were the OP making the comment, my bad

Comment: @NikosM. Then I would have had my name highlighted in blue ;)